# using a type alias when splitting template class into header and implementation file

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, using

I have a templated class which is split into a `.hpp` file and a `.ipp` which has quite a long type in it. While refactoring I wanted to write a type alias for that type so the code could be a lot more readable. But no matter what I do I cannot get the type alias to be recognized in the `.ipp` file.

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

container.hpp:

```
template <class T>
class container {
public:
    using TypeAlias = T;
    container(const TypeAlias& a);
    const TypeAlias& getA() const;
private:
    TypeAlias a;
};

#include "container.ipp"
```

container.ipp:

```
template <class T>
container<T>::container(const TypeAlias& a) : a(a)
{

}

template <class T>
const TypeAlias& container<T>::getA() const
{
    return this->a;
}
```

When compiling this the following error occurs:

```
./container.ipp:8:7: error: unknown type name 'TypeAlias'
const TypeAlias& container<T>::getA() const
```

Obviously in this case it doesn't make much sense to introduce the `TypeAlias` but in my actual program it could make a huge difference. Is there anything I can do to make the TypeAlias available in the `.ipp` file?

Comment: I assume the `#include "container.ipp"` is actually at the end of container.hpp, not at the beginning of container.ipp.

Comment: @aschepler Yes I copied it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a class member like `container<T>::getA`, things after the name of the member (`getA` here) are looked up in the scope of the class, but things before it are not.  Essentially, if the compiler tries to understand things in order, when the declaration begins with `const TypeAlias&`, it doesn't yet know that it should look inside `container<T>` to figure out what `TypeAlias` could mean.

So using normal function syntax, you would need to specify that `TypeAlias` is a member type:

```
template <class T>
const typename container<T>::TypeAlias& container<T>::getA() const
{
    return this->a;
}
```

But this is one advantage of the "trailing return type" syntax (valid in C++11 and later): Just by changing the order of things, it lets you use members of the class within the return type more simply:

```
template <class T>
auto container<T>::getA() const -> const TypeAlias&
{
    return this->a;
}
```